# How to display embedded templates in modal template dialog?

Tags: templates, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'd like to instead of rendering templates in `#content` display dynamically first a modal dialog and then templates. Where should be the code responsible for displaying the modal automatically containing the chosen template? After all this, how can I close and remove modal class after cancel? This is current code: [git](https://github.com/bartroza/ModalLogin). I'm learning backbone and don't know what the correct pattern is.

Session router:

```
($, Backbone, App, Session, Layout, AlertQueue) ->
  class App.Routers.SessionsRouter extends Backbone.Router
    initialize: (options) ->
      @user  = options.user
      @token = options.token
      @session = new Session(@user)
      @user.on('change', =>
        @session = new Session(@user)
        @token.fetch()
      )

    routes:
      "signup":               "newRegistration"
      "signin":               "newSession"

    newRegistration: ->
      View = require 'views/registrations/new_view'
      Model = require 'models/registration'
      @view = new View(model: new Model(), user: @user)
      # Layout.setContent(@view)
      # Dialog.show(@view)??

    newSession: ->
      View = require 'views/sessions/new_view'
      @view = new View(model: @session, user: @user, token: @token)
      # Layout.setContent(@view)
```

Layout helper, now displays content in static container:

```
($, Backbone, App) ->
  class Layout extends Backbone.Model
    setContent: (content) ->
      do @currentContent.close if @currentContent?
      @currentContent = content
      ($ '#content').html content.render().el

  App.Helpers.Layout = new Layout
```

Current modal template:

```
#dialog.modal.hide.fade
  .modal-header
    %a.close{href: "#"} ×
    / %h3=title
  .modal-body
    #dialog_content
  .modal-footer
    %a.btn.danger.yes Yes
    %a.btn.secondary.no No
```

Current modal dialog view:

```
($, Backbone, App) ->

  class App.Views.Common.DialogView extends Backbone.View
    template: JST["common/dialog"]

    initialize: (options) ->
        super(options)

    render: ->
      $(@el).html(@template())
      $('.modal', @el).modal()
      return @

    show: ->
      $('.modal', @el).modal('show')

    hide: ->
      $('.modal', @el).modal('hide')
```

Current dialog initializer:

```
($, Backbone, App, FormView, DialogModalView) ->

  class App.Views.Common.DialogView extends FormView

    className: -> "modal"

    initialize: ->
      view = new DialogModalView()

      $(view.render().el).find(".modal-body").append(@template())
      $(view.render().el.children).modal('show')
```

Session view extends Dialog view:

```
($, Backbone, App, Session, DialogView) ->

  class App.Views.Sessions.NewView extends DialogView
    template: JST["sessions/new"]
```

Comment: so if I understand correctly you don't want to call `modal('show')` in your view but instead want Bootstrap to do that for you so you can just render whatever inside that modal?

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to place the modal related logic to the view, which renders the template.
When the render method of the view called it renders the template and then to decouple concrete view logic from common modal functionality it should trigger an event, for example render.

The view itself can listen for this event, and when it triggers call modal on the rendered template. You can name the callback for example onRender. If modals related to some application logic, modal creation can also be handled outside of the view with this event driven approach.

This event driven template and callback logic is implemented in [Backbone Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) (of course the handling of modal is not in the plugin, but it renders the template and fires the events). Take a look at it, besides this it has many features that saves You time by automating these repetitive tasks.